# Predef.StringCanBuildFrom's behaviour

Tags: scala

I stumbled accross `Predef.StringCanBuildFrom` surprising implementation that breaks assumptions I was making on `CanBuildFrom` in my code. Here's the implementation:

```
implicit def stringCanBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] = 
    new CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] {
      def apply(from: String) = apply()
      def apply() = mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder
}
```

It seems totally unnatural that `apply(String)` simply ignores the parameter. To me, the correct implementation should be

```
implicit def stringCanBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] = 
    new CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] {
      def apply(from: String) = apply() ++= from
      def apply() = mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder
}
```

but it seems so trivial that I can't believe I'm the ony one to have spotted that since the language exists. I was tempted to open an issue for this, but if I'm missing any good reason to not do what I proposed, please tell me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of `apply(from)`.

It's documentation says:

> Creates a new builder on request of a collection.
>   **@param from** the collection requesting the builder to be created.
>   **@return** a builder for collections of type `To` with element type
>   `Elem`. The collections framework usually arranges
>   things so that the created builder will build the same
>   kind of collection as `from`.

So it's used to resolve the builder using the runtime type of the collection, and maybe to copy some auxiliary data from the original collection. For example, the implementation in `scala.collection.generic.GenTraversableFactory#GenericCanBuildFrom` is simply `def apply(from: Coll) = from.genericBuilder[A]`. As you see no actual data is copied from the argument collection.

Actually, your implementation of `CanBuildFrom` would produce wrong results for the standard implementations of `map`, `flatMap` and other generic functions:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable

implicit def stringCanBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] =
  new CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String] {
    def apply(from: String) = apply() ++= from
    def apply() = mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder
  }

scala> "foo".map(identity)(stringCanBuildFrom)
res1: String = foofoo
```

Comment: Mmm, I should have read more examples of usages. That's right, they're always assuming that a builder is initialized empty, which explains the duplicate `"foo"` in your example. Cheers :)